# How to pass String value from one void method to another void method

Tags: java, android, string, void

I have two void method in the same class. Method2 get data from textview and it stored in a string. I want to get Method2 string in Method1 string.
Note: It is an android project.
Code is here:

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

void Method2()
{
    //this place i want to get str1 value like this:
    // String str2=str1
}
void Method1(View view)
{
    String str1=textView.getText().toString();
}
}
```

Comment: What about using global variables ? Or just change the return value of your methods ?

Comment: Why can't you declare `str1` as class level variable?

Comment: Either declare variable str1 at class level or 
Change return type of Method1 to return string and return this str1 and call method1 from method2.
    void Method2() {
        //this place i want to get str1 value like this:
        // String str2=method1(view)
    }

    String Method1(View view) {
        return textView.getText().toString();
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

public static String s1 ;
public static String s2 ;


    void Method1(View view) {
      s1 = textView.getText().toString();
    }
 void Method2() {
       s2 = s1 ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why s1 and s2 are static?

Comment: because the  methods will modify their values .

Comment: Methods can also modify non static variables.

Answer (score 0):

Learn and follow Java coding standards.  This simple class fails the test.

Method 1 should not return void; it should return the String from the View.

Method 2 should not have an empty parameter list; it should have a String parameter that lets you pass in the value you want.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void method2(String s) {
        //this place i want to get str1 value like this:
        // String str2=str1
    }

    public String method1(View view) {
         return textView.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

You don't have an example of how `method1` will get a reference to a `View`.

This implementation will allow you to get the `String` out of the `View` and pass it to `method2`.  Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to add a parameter to `method2()`

```
void method2(String str1) {
    //this place i want to get str1 value like this:
    // String str2=str1
}
```

And call it from `method1`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want both methods to be of `void` return type, you will need to use a class variable. In your code, `str1` is local to `Method1`, and cannot be accessed from outside `Method1`. Using a class variable:

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String str1; 

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    void Method2() {
        String str2 = str1;
    }

    void Method1(View view) {
        str1 = textView.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if `Method2` should be executed after `Method1`:

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    void Method2(String str) {
        String str2 = str1;
    }

    void Method1(View view) {
        String str1 = textView.getText().toString();
        Method2(str1); //pass the string to Method1
    }
}
```